# Alternatives available to generic 2d array without using suppressing warnings

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Is there any design issues if I want to return a 2d array of `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair<L,R>` from a function. The following will be the function prototype:

```
public MutablePair[][] f() {
    //code goes here
}
```

Note that since java does not allow arrays for generic I have to return a raw type and suppress the corresponding warnings generated by compiler.

The other alternative is to use `List<list<Mutable<Integer, Integer>>>` which looks too verbose to me. Moreover I do not really need a list interface(the size of 2d array is fixed). I can also use ArrayList but again that would be too verbose. I want to avoid these.

So my question is what problems can arise with such function declaratiosn. Is it totally unacceptable to declare and use such functions. What is the general recommended practice in such a case. Or is it best to use the verbose ways?

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you consider creating an extending class `IntPair extends MutablePair<Integer, Integer>` and creating an array of that?

Comment: @arshajii That would just be an extra class with no additional functionality. It would be as good as creating my own pair class. So what's the point of writing new class like this. Moreover if another tomorrow I need a pair of strings then I would need another class. So I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: "Note that since java does not allow arrays for generic I have to return a raw type and suppress the corresponding warnings generated by compiler." It's perfectly fine to return `MutablePair<L,R>[][]` and have variables of that type, etc. You just need to cast it to that type to begin with.

Comment: @newacct that's what made me think that can there be potential risks with such type of casting. I am new to java so could not evaluate properly. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Guava Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table)'s might be relevant to you.. They allow non-integer key, values which you will have to set to regular integers, and have a bunch of [utility methods](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html) which might prove to be useful to you. [ArrayTable's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html) in particular might be a good fit.